# How to set textView.setText before Activity Launch

Tags: android, android-activity, launch

In my App, when Options **Menu -> About -> Here** is pressed, I'm showing info with `DialogActivity`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
TextView  textview  = OptionSelDialog.optionsTextView; //(static assigned and pulled in MainActivity)
       case R.id.action_about:
            textview.setText("This About Msg");
            startActivity(new Intent(this, OptionSelDialog.class));
            break;
```

Here `OptionSelDialog` is separate `Activity`, not yet called from anywhere.
I tried:

1. Calling `startActivity` of `OptionSelDialog` from `MainActivity.OnCreate`
2. Intilizing textview in `OptionSelDialog` construtor (I know this is wrong )

Finally, Activity is crashing with `textView is NULL ;`
One more thing, from second time app launch it works fine.

Please help with solution.

Comment: start activity with text parameter

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your way is not recommended. We have a lot of ways to do it. Example:

1. Hold the data into memory and load it to textview after you start activity
2. When you start new activity, you should pass a bundle to your second activity and from your second activty, you display that value to textview.

   ```
   Intent optionSelDialogIntent = new Intent(xxx.this,OptionSelDialog.class);
   ```

   `optionSelDialogIntent.putExtra("your key", "your text value");
   startActivity(optionSelDialogIntent);`

At your second activity:

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("your key")) {
        yourData = bundle.getString("your key");
    }
```

then init your textview and setText with yourData. That's all.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply .
mean while I have also tried the same , worked perfectly.